# win cmd: Deleting files that have no sidecars

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, windows-7

Having troubles with cmd syntax, trying to delete files with specific extension in a specific folder that don't have sidecars. eg.: if folder contains:

> 1.A, 1.B, 2.A, 3.A, 4.A, 4.B

bat should only delete

> 2.A, 3.A

..hope that makes sense.

The code I've got so far must be real close, unfortunatelly not working

```
@echo off

FOR %%x IN (%1\*.A) DO 
(
    IF not exist "%1\%x.B" del "%1\%x.A"
)
```

Any help mostly appreciated.

Comment: You're using `%%x` to define the variable and `%x` to use it; you need to use `%%x` to use it as well.

Comment: The `(` must also be on the same physical line as the `do`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments to question are correct

- FOR variable percents must be consistently doubled when used in batch script
- Open paren must be on same line as DO. But there isn't any need for parens with such a simple script.

Also, you want only the base name of the FOR variable, so you need the `~n` modifier.

I made the code a bit more robust by using PUSHD at beginning.

```
@echo off
pushd %1
for %%F in (*.A) do if not exist "%%~nF.B" del "%%F"
popd
```